# onsenでボタンを押したら外部リンクに飛ぶようにしたいのですが

Tags: onsen-ui

onClickに定義すればよいのでしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

onclickで大丈夫です。

```
onclick="window.open(url, target, options);"
```

target
・_self:URLがホワイトリストに載っている場合は、Cordova WebView。それ以外は、InAppBrowser
・_blank:InAppBrowser
・_system:システムのWebブラウザ

options ※InAppBrowserで使用するオプション。
・location:
  yes:ロケーションバー表示
  no:ロケーションバー非表示

詳細は[Inappbrowserプラグイン](http://docs.monaca.mobi/cur/ja/reference/phonegap_34/ja/inappbrowser/)をご参照ください。

Comment: 抽象的な質問ですみませんでした。
回答ありがとうございます。